# How does Tumblr create such a smooth hover effect for its nav bar links? Possible without JavaScript?

Tags: css, html, animation

Hovering over the nav bar links (e.g., Text, Photo, Quote) on the Tumblr dashboard creates a smooth effect where the icon rises about 5-10 pixels then gradually falls back into place, as if there is animation.

Tumblr dashboard: http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard

Using plain CSS to achieve the same effect (i.e., position:relative; top:-8px) on our site creates a jarring effect when the icon snaps back into place immediately.

Is there a way to achieve this effect without JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use CSS3 transition effects DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/xejsM/500/

```
a {
    color:blue;
    /* First we need to help some browsers along for this to work.
     Just because a vendor prefix is there, doesn't mean it will
     work in a browser made by that vendor either, it's just for
     future-proofing purposes I guess. */
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
}
```